# Can "couldn't have done" be used in subjunctive mood?

Tags: conditional-constructions, verb-forms

> We **couldn't** have finished the work ahead of time without your help.

Does the sentence make sense to you? Can "couldn't have done" be used in subjunctive mood?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the sentence makes perfect sense. It is quite conventional.

Strictly speaking, it's in the "conditional mood", not the "subjunctive mood", although grammatical distinctions like moods are rather sloppy in English and terminology is not well standardized. The reason it's conditional is because it depends on "without your help". "Without your help" describes the imaginary hypothesis; "we couldn't have…" describes the consequence of that hypothesis.

You could also just say that it's the "indicative mood", and **couldn't** is just the past tense of **can't**. Well, I said that moods are sloppy in English grammar.

I think that for purposes of learning English, the most important thing to know is that people choose the word **could** because the **-ould** words seem to mean a condition that results from something else that you're imagining. The same **-ould** words also suggest the past tense, which also fits this sentence. The terminology doesn't really matter.

Comment: Good summary.  Grammatical accounts of English verbs suffer desperately from being pressed into the mold of Romance languages.

Comment: I don't really undertand why it doesn't follow the 3rd conditional structure (if + past perfect, would + have + past participle), what rule does it follow? Is it an exception? Thanks

Comment: @silvia I (native AmE) don't see it as an exception to anything. What rule would it break?